# How to make text to XML transformation faster?

Tags: algorithm, xslt, xpath, xslt-3.0

I have a question about how to make a XSLT script faster. Input is a text file with time measurements like this:

```
67235 | 8 | ecus | Started | ecus
67306 | 2 | step1 | Started | ecus/step1
67384 | 2 | step7 | Started | ecus/step1/step7
67387 | 2 | step28 | Started | ecus/step1/step2/step28
67413 | 28 | step28 | Stopped | ecus/step1/step2/step28
67416 | 3 | step14 | Started | ecus/step1/step2/step14
67431 | 2 | step19 | Started | ecus/step1/step2/step14/step19
67786 | 357 | step19 | Stopped | ecus/step1/step2/step14/step19
67789 | 3 | step57 | Started | ecus/step1/step2/step14/step57
67801 | 15 | step57 | Stopped | ecus/step1/step2/step14/step57
67804 | 2 | step8 | Started | ecus/step1/step2/step14/step8
67805 | 3 | step8 | Stopped | ecus/step1/step2/step14/step8
67807 | 2 | step9 | Started | ecus/step1/step2/step14/step9
67808 | 3 | step9 | Stopped | ecus/step1/step2/step14/step9
67811 | 3 | step12 | Started | ecus/step1/step2/step14/step12
67820 | 12 | step12 | Stopped | ecus/step1/step2/step14/step12
67823 | 2 | step13 | Started | ecus/step1/step2/step14/step13
67824 | 3 | step13 | Stopped | ecus/step1/step2/step14/step13
67827 | 3 | step15 | Started | ecus/step1/step2/step14/step15
69235 | 1411 | step15 | Stopped | ecus/step1/step2/step14/step15
69238 | 3 | step16 | Started | ecus/step1/step2/step14/step16
69238 | 3 | step16 | Stopped | ecus/step1/step2/step14/step16
69241 | 2 | step18 | Started | ecus/step1/step2/step14/step18
69373 | 134 | step18 | Stopped | ecus/step1/step2/step14/step18
69404 | 2 | step30 | Started | ecus/step1/step2/step14/step30
69722 | 320 | step30 | Stopped | ecus/step1/step2/step14/step30
69736 | 3 | step31 | Started | ecus/step1/step2/step14/step31

[...]
```

I have a XSLT template that transforms this data in two steps. First step is to make a "flat" XML structure from text; output looks like this:

```
<profile>
  <step ord="1" ts="67235" time="8" info="Started" path="ecus" root="ecus" level="0"/>
  <step ord="2" ts="67306" time="2" info="Started" path="ecus/step1" root="step1" level="1"/>
  <step ord="3" ts="67384" time="2" info="Started" path="ecus/step1/step7" root="step7" level="2"/>
  <step ord="4" ts="67387" time="2" info="Started" path="ecus/step1/step2/step28" root="step28" level="3"/>
  <step ord="5" ts="67413" time="28" info="Stopped" path="ecus/step1/step2/step28" root="step28" level="3"/>
  <step ord="6" ts="67416" time="3" info="Started" path="ecus/step1/step2/step14" root="step14" level="3"/>
  <step ord="7" ts="67431" time="2" info="Started" path="ecus/step1/step2/step14/step19" root="step19" level="4"/>
  <step ord="8" ts="67786" time="357" info="Stopped" path="ecus/step1/step2/step14/step19" root="step19" level="4"/>
  <step ord="9" ts="67789" time="3" info="Started" path="ecus/step1/step2/step14/step57" root="step57" level="4"/>
  <step ord="10" ts="67801" time="15" info="Stopped" path="ecus/step1/step2/step14/step57" root="step57" level="4"/>
  <step ord="11" ts="67804" time="2" info="Started" path=" ecus/step1/step2/step14/step8" root="step8" level="4"/>
  <step ord="12" ts="67805" time="3" info="Stopped" path=" ecus/step1/step2/step14/step8" root="step8" level="4"/>
  <step ord="13" ts="67807" time="2" info="Started" path="ecus/step1/step2/step14/step9" root="step9" level="4"/>
  <step ord="14" ts="67808" time="3" info="Stopped" path="ecus/step1/step2/step14/step9" root="step9" level="4"/>
  <step ord="15" ts="67811" time="3" info="Started" path="ecus/step1/step2/step14/step12" root="step12" level="4"/>
[...]
```

... the second step transforms this flat XML to a XML tree where the `path` attribute value is represented as structure:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<profile>
   <ecus start="67235" time="3105043">
      <step1 start="67306" time="2363792">
         <step7 start="67384" time="9952">
            <step28 start="67387" time="28"/>
            <step14 start="67416" time="9920">
               <step19 start="67431" time="357"/>
               <step57 start="67789" time="15"/>
               <step8 start="67804" time="3"/>
               <step9 start="67807" time="3"/>
               <step12 start="67811" time="12"/>
               <step13 start="67823" time="3"/>
               <step15 start="67827" time="1411"/>
               <step16 start="69238" time="3"/>
               <step18 start="69241" time="134"/>
               <step30 start="69404" time="320"/>
               <step31 start="69736" time="3"/>
               <step16 start="69736" time="1"/>
               <step29 start="69755" time="35"/>
               <step6 start="69808" time="917">
                  <step20 start="70084" time="641">
                     <step23 start="70099" time="9"/>
                     <step26 start="70114" time="3"/> 
[...]
```

As code for the second step i am using this:

```
<xsl:template match="step" mode="unflatten1">
    <xsl:variable name="start" select="current()"/>
    <xsl:variable name="stop" select="$start/following-sibling::step[@info='Stopped' and @path = $start/@path][1]"/>
    <xsl:element name="{$start/@root}">
        <xsl:attribute name="start" select="$start/@ts"/>
        <xsl:attribute name="time" select="$stop/@time"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="key('startedthreads',@level + 1)[number(@ord) &gt; number($start/@ord) and number(@ord) &lt; number($stop/@ord)]" mode="unflatten1"/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

It works fine but the performance using this template seems to be rather poor.

I expected 1 to 2 seconds for step 2 using a original input file with about 30000 lines (see link to project below), but it lasts 4 to 5 seconds on a i7 processor 10th gen. platform :-/

My question: are there settings or other methods or techniques (like indexing the `ord` or combination of attributes) or functions in XPath or XSLT that could help to make step 2 running faster?

You will find the code here: https://gitlab.com/ms452206/socode20200906

Comment: You have used one key it seems, based on the `@level` attribute. Using more keys (in XSLT 3 you can have `composite` keys) should give further performance improvements. As could give the use of `for-each-group group-starting-with/group-ending-with` or grouping in general. I am currently not sure whether you need to group by `@level` and/or `@root`, perhaps you can reduce the code samples a bit to give a simple, but representative and complete example of intermediary flat XML and the corresponding XML output you want.

Comment: @MartinHonnen I have added a smaller input file `main.txt` in the [repository](https://gitlab.com/ms452206/socode20200906). The interims file for this is `xml/flatmain.xml` and result file is `xml/main.xml`. I've never used the statements that you mentioned, I will explore it ...

Comment: With the smaller sample I was able to put together some code using `for-each-group group-starting-with/group-ending-with` in a recursive function, I have posted the XSLT in an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a Saxon extension function can also help making the processing faster.

The current "templates benchmark" with stylesheet input [`profile.txt`](https://gitlab.com/ms452206/socode20200906/-/blob/master/profile.txt) and expected output [`profile.xml`](https://gitlab.com/ms452206/socode20200906/-/blob/master/xml/profile.xml) :

[image]

[image]

- Template `txt2xml_s0` simply does nothing (hence only to show java and Saxon loading time)
- Template `txt2xml_s1` is the original solution (not bad but improvable as revealed by answers above)
- Template `txt2xml_s4` implements the first [approach from MH](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63763607/5924595)
- Template `txt2xml_s5` is the approach with Saxon extension function, best performance and lowest memory consuming; *my preferred solution now*
- Template `txt2xml_s6` implements the second, less memory consuming [approach from MH](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63763607/5924595)

I've updated the [repository](https://gitlab.com/ms452206/socode20200906). It includes all known solutions. The extension function code is [`ScanFile.java`](https://gitlab.com/ms452206/socode20200906/-/blob/master/ScanFile.java).

Answer (score 1):

I have tried it with `for-each-group group-starting-with/group-ending-with` and XSLT 3:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:mf="http://example.com/mf"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">
    
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:function name="mf:group" as="element()*">
      <xsl:param name="steps" as="element()*"/>
      <xsl:param name="level" as="xs:integer"/>
      <xsl:for-each-group
        select="$steps" group-starting-with="step[@level = $level and @info = 'Started']">
          <xsl:variable name="start" select="."/>
          <xsl:for-each-group 
             select="current-group() except ." 
             group-ending-with="step[@level = $level and @info = 'Stopped' and @path = $start/@path]">
             <xsl:variable name="stop" select="current-group()[last()]"/>
          <xsl:element name="{normalize-space($start/@root)}">
              <xsl:attribute name="start" select="$start/@ts"/>
              <xsl:attribute name="time" select="$stop/@time"/>
              <xsl:sequence select="mf:group(current-group()[position() lt last()], $level + 1)"/>
          </xsl:element>              
          </xsl:for-each-group>
      </xsl:for-each-group>
  </xsl:function>

  <xsl:template match="profile">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:sequence
            select="mf:group(step, 0)"/>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/ehW12g8

Running Saxon HE 10.2 Java on my Notebook against your flattened XML takes `Execution time: 854.9807ms`.

I the first step I think with XSLT/XPath 3 using `unparsed-text-lines` instead of `xsl:analyze-string` is also easier and performs better:

```
   <xsl:variable name="flatprofile">
            <profile>
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="unparsed-text-available($file, $encoding)">
                        <xsl:variable name="content" select="unparsed-text($file, $encoding)"/>
                        <xsl:for-each select="unparsed-text-lines($file, $encoding)">
                                <step>
                                    <xsl:for-each select="tokenize(.,'\|')">
                                        <xsl:variable name="pos" select="position()"/>
                                        <xsl:choose>
                                            <xsl:when test="$pos = 1">
                                                <xsl:attribute name="ts" select="normalize-space(.)"/>
                                            </xsl:when>
                                            <xsl:when test="$pos = 2">
                                                <xsl:attribute name="time" select="normalize-space(.)"/>
                                            </xsl:when>
                                            <xsl:when test="$pos = 4">
                                                <xsl:attribute name="info" select="normalize-space(.)"/>
                                            </xsl:when>
                                            <xsl:when test="$pos = 5">
                                                <xsl:attribute name="path" select="."/>
                                                <xsl:attribute name="root" select="tokenize(.,'/')[last()]"/>
                                                <xsl:attribute name="level" select="string-length(.) - string-length(translate(., '/', ''))"/>
                                            </xsl:when>
                                        </xsl:choose>
                                    </xsl:for-each>
                                </step>                   
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <xsl:variable name="error">
                            <xsl:text>Error reading "</xsl:text>
                            <xsl:value-of select="$file"/>
                        </xsl:variable>
                        <xsl:message><xsl:value-of select="$error"/></xsl:message>
                        <xsl:value-of select="$error"/>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </profile>
       
    </xsl:variable>
```

The main template would then use

```
<xsl:template match="/" name="txt2xml">
    <profile>
        <xsl:sequence select="mf:group($flatprofile/profile/step, 0)"/>
    </profile>
</xsl:template>
```

My system then needs 1.1 or 1.2 seconds for the whole transformation, using Java 8 and Saxon 10.2 HE.

To simplify the whole approach (and in the hope that could further reduce the time needed) I switched from a two step "text -> XML" and "recursive grouping of the XML" to a recursive grouping of a sequence of light-weight maps created from the plain text:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0" xmlns:map="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/map"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:mf="http://example.com/mf" exclude-result-prefixes="#all">

    <xsl:output indent="yes" method="xml"/>
    
    <xsl:param name="encoding" as="xs:string" select="'utf-8'"/>

    <xsl:param name="file" as="xs:string" select="''"/>

    <xsl:function name="mf:group" as="element()*">
        <xsl:param name="steps" as="map(xs:string, xs:anyAtomicType)*"/>
        <xsl:param name="level" as="xs:integer"/>
        <xsl:for-each-group select="$steps"
            group-starting-with=".[?level eq $level and ?info eq 'Started']">
            <xsl:variable name="start" select="."/>
            <xsl:for-each-group select="current-group() => tail()"
                group-ending-with=".[?level eq $level and ?info eq 'Stopped' and ?path eq $start?path]">
                <xsl:variable name="stop" select="current-group()[last()]"/>
                <xsl:element name="{normalize-space($start?root)}">
                    <xsl:attribute name="start" select="$start?ts"/>
                    <xsl:attribute name="time" select="$stop?time"/>
                    <xsl:sequence
                        select="mf:group(current-group()[position() lt last()], $level + 1)"/>
                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:for-each-group>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:function>

    <xsl:template name="xsl:initial-template">
        <profile>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="unparsed-text-available($file, $encoding)">
                    <xsl:sequence
                        select="
                            mf:group(
                                unparsed-text-lines($file, $encoding)
                                !
                                (let $tokens := tokenize(., '\|') ! normalize-space(),
                                     $token5 := $tokens[5],
                                     $token5Tokens := tokenize($token5, '/')
                                return
                                    map {
                                        'ts': $tokens[1],
                                        'time': $tokens[2],
                                        'info': $tokens[4],
                                        'path': $token5,
                                        'root': $token5Tokens[last()],
                                        'level': count($token5Tokens) - 1
                                    }), 
                                0
                            )"
                    />
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:variable name="error">
                        <xsl:text>Error reading "</xsl:text>
                        <xsl:value-of select="$file"/>
                    </xsl:variable>
                    <xsl:message>
                        <xsl:value-of select="$error"/>
                    </xsl:message>
                    <xsl:value-of select="$error"/>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </profile>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

However, while this slightly reduces memory consumption, it does seem to perform a bit slower than the text to XML followed by recursive grouping of the XML approach.

Comment: The time measurement given in my question was not perfectly correct, the 7 to 8 sec were for both steps together :). Hence step 2 was only about 4 to 6 seconds. But yes, your solution using `for-each-group` improves processing time for step 2. I've measured it is under one second now (for both SaxonHE  9 and 10 there is no much difference) on my PC. I see I can also improve step 1?! Thank you for the code!

Comment: @mark61, as an experiment I have added a different approach creating a sequence of maps holding the data extracted from the sequence of text lines and then recursively grouping the maps instead of XML. It seems to reduce memory consumption but performs a bit slower than the recursive grouping of the XML.

Comment: How did you determine memory consumption? Are you using Saxon PE/EE edition and/or with streaming mode? I have Saxon HE and measured execution time and memory using `/usr/bin/time -l` command, see [results](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63858203/5924595) where template `txt2xml_s6` is the template with the `!` operator. It is not so good in lower memory consumption.

Comment: @mark61, I tend to rely on the Saxon command line option `-t` which gives some diagnostics output for time and memory consumption. It shows e.g. `Memory used: 123Mb` for the map based approach and e.g. `Memory used: 148Mb` for the intermediary XML based approach, both run with your profile.txt as the text input.

Comment: I have found out different results (see [Benchmarks.txt](https://gitlab.com/ms452206/socode20200906/-/blob/master/Benchmarks.txt). Your first solution performs better in memory consumption than the second. Might be caused by different plattforms and java engines.

Answer (score 0):

It's always tricky reverse engineering requirements from code, but at least in this case it's working code!

The crux seems to be

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="key('startedthreads',@level + 1)
    [number(@ord) &gt; number($start/@ord) and 
     number(@ord) &lt; number($stop/@ord)]" mode="unflatten1"/>
```

The call on key() isn't going to be very useful because it will select a large number of elements for each key value. (In fact I recall a recent performance bug relating to keys with large numbers of duplicates, but I can't locate it right now).

As a first step I would be inclined to group the data by `@level`, so you can then select all the steps at a given level quickly.

Then I think you need to ensure that the search of a given level stops when you find the first `@ord` that is greater than `$stop/@ord`. You know that the data is sorted, but Saxon doesn't, and you somehow need to take advantage of this knowledge. One way would be to search the data explicitly using `xsl:iterate` which allows you to break off when the relevant conditions are encountered. Another option might be to use the (new) saxon:items-until() extension function [1], or perhaps to use a range key [2]. Or you could do it the old way using a recursive function that calls itself one sibling at a time.

[1] https://saxonica.com/documentation/index.html#!functions/saxon/items-until

[2] https://saxonica.com/documentation/index.html#!functions/saxon/key-map